# GraphQl fragment to Pojo

Tags: rest, web-services, graphql, pojo, graphql-java

Recently I had to switch a **GraphQl endpoint** for a **REST API** which is just a layer on top of the **GraphQl endpoint** that I was querying since the beginning of the project.

Querying `GraphQl` was easy, simple and thru some libs provided by Netflix

I was able to deserialize the responses into `POJOs` (just need to provide the schema), all of this in order to apply some business logic.

Now that I had to switch to the `REST API`, I'm having a hard time trying to deserialize the responses and I don't really like the idea of creating hardcode `POJOs` for each different response (using the fragments).

So far I couldn't find any lib to create either a `JSON` or a `POJO` given a `GraphQl` fragment. Do you know if is actually possibile to achieve something like that?

I know It doesn't make any sense that I had to switch to the `REST API` but it doesn't depend by me

Thank you in advance !!